# Explain opportunity gap in SoP without proving it?

Tags: statement-of-purpose

I'm applying for PhD programs in Computer Science (experimental part of AI/ML), and writing my SoP for it.

A part of SoP is supposed to talk about examples of what kind of work one wants to do later during PhD.
I've developed some opportunity gap analyses with current state of the art, to propose some research in SoP.
This is based on a set of experiments and their results (line graphs, heatmaps etc) which support my point a lot more.

Should these results be included in SoP?

- If not: how do I establish that there is a opportunity gap here, a problem to solve?  (without these experiments, its not obvious why there is a problem at all)
- If yes: I've not seen this in any of the SoPs. I'll have to establish the experiment setting, explain the plots and then suggest solution. This seems excessive, since I do want to write about other things.

How detailed should I be?

Comment: Is "opportunity gap" a regularly studied thing in your field? I've never heard the term. In other words, will people immediately understand the term when you make application?

Comment: @Buffy Yes. I picked it up at a conference where my paper was accepted - everyone seemed to know. Essentially means you have established that there is a problem to solve despite state of the art. Borrowed from business analysis (e.g. why have Lyft when we have Uber?)

Comment: I definitely would not assume that just because you were at a conference where, in your perception, "everyone seemed to know", it follows that the reader of your SoP will be familiar with this term.

Comment: To me, an "opportunity gap" is another label for the "achievement gap" used for example in describing racial disparities. It's meant to emphasize the contribution of different access to opportunities in establishing observed gaps in achievement. I see it's also used in business, but it doesn't seem like it's being used the way you are using it.

Comment: I agree with Bryan, this *sounds* like you're asking how to discuss your lack of opportunities growing up, but it reads like you're asking whether you should write about a specific analysis/something in CS in your individual SOP, which makes this off-topic

Comment: "Opportunity gap" isn't necessarily an AI/ML term-of-art, but the meaning is intuitive: certain problems are already fully leveraging a given insight, whereas other problems really haven't. In context, I doubt this term would confuse a group of CS professors.

Comment: An opportunity gap analysis in this case is to help _you_ understand how you might want to craft your career path. It’s a tool. Use the results to help you choose goals prudently. Then a concise explanatory note in your SoP will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, do not put technical results in your SoP.** These results should be written up in an appropriate venue -- if not a real paper, perhaps a preprint or even an article  on your website. Then you can briefly (in a few sentences) explain your interest / past work, with a citation to the full write-up.

The purpose of the SoP is to...well....state your purpose in applying to graduate school. For example, if your purpose is to become an expert in applying machine learning algorithms to medical images so that you can be an expert witness at medical malpractice trials, then you probably don't want an advisor whose interest is in reinforcement learning for cooperative swarms. So it's good to state your interest in specific types of machine learning or application domains. You can also explain your future goals (why are you interested in this -- not cute stories from your childhood, but actual reasons and potential future career paths) and why you think you are likely to be successful in pursuing these goals (e.g., because of previous successful experiences in similar endeavors).

However, this is not the document where  you propose your thesis topic and get buy-in from your advisor. While it's possible one of your ideas will indeed end up being your thesis, it's also very likely that you'll end up going in a totally new direction. It is good to keep an open mind about this.

Answer (score 1):

Without stressing or, perhaps, even mentioning "opportunity gap" you can explain that you have some limited evidence that the state of the art of X is sub-optimal and that you would like to see if you can improve on that.

Some explanation of X is needed, of course, but probably no more than a couple of sentences. And perhaps a bit more on why you think improvement is possible and the direction in which to look.

But "opportunity gap" per se is not the important message. X... is.

Keep in mind, of course, that your goal should be to explore the unknown, not prove a point that you think is valid. Negative results are results and forcing only supporting evidence leads to error (and blindness).

And, depending on where you are, you might need to keep an open mind about what questions you do wind up exploring. An advisor may have important things to say.

Comment: "keep an open mind about what questions you do wind up exploring"  That's important: the criterion for awarding a PhD is "make a substantial original contribution to knowledge", not "make the same substantial original contribution to knowledge you planned for at the start".